# Which learning algorithms are suitable for data leakage detection and prevention?

Tags: learning-algorithms

I'm investigating applications of AI algorithms which can be used for data leakage detection and prevention within an intranet network (like [Forcepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcepoint)). More specifically detecting traffic patterns. I'm new to this.

Which learning algorithms are most suitable for this goal? [EA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm), [GA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), [ANN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) (which one) or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to fall broadly into the regime of a [classification problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) as you want to classify an outgoing communication as "contains proprietary information" or "does not contain proprietary information".  As such, any classification approach could be applied.  Neural Networks certainly seem like a valid approach, but you might also get good mileage out of Random Forests, Support Vector Machines, a Naive Bayes classifier, etc.

GA's are more aimed towards optimization than classification, so I wouldn't say that a GA, in and of itself, would map cleanly to solving this kind of problem. If GA's had applicability here, I think it would be more likely to be in terms of training a model rooted in one of the other techniques.